# Finding a matrix solution directly with Mathematica

Tags: equation-solving, matrix

I have two matrices say

```
M={{a,b,c},{b,d,f},{c,f,e}}
```

and

```
G={{A,0,B},{0,B,A},{A,B,B}}
```

Now I have done

```
U=Transpose[M].G.M
```

and

```
T=Conjugate[G]
```

Now following the equality

```
Solve[U==T,G]
```

Is this possible or any other technique to directly get the reduced G matrix due to the equality without solving this by hand

Comment: At the moment  your code does not run for me. What kind of transformation are you trying to implement / what kind of property are you trying to impose on `G`? Perhaps if you can provide some context we might be able to help better.

Comment: @MarcoB You can see [https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.01206.pdf](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.01206.pdf). Here the resultant M_\nu is determined through above procedure. I am asking about any simple procedure to directly compare the equality and get reduced M_\nu. Since I know the last equation of mine Solve[U==T,G] can't be solved by this way other than doing rigorously by hand

Comment: you may try Reduce[U==T, {a,b}] Though I gave up after 10 minutes...assuming I understood what you're looking for...however am I understanding in the paper you're simply looking the diagonal matrix of $M_\nu$ ?

Comment: @morbo No at first I need the reduced M_\nu from the equality, Since this form is required to find the diagonalization matrix